# Intellisense doesn't work in .spec files (works when I remove .spec)

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am writing test in **Jest** and files have **.spec.ts** extension.

I noticed that when I reference my classes, **vscode** doesn't automatically resolve their name and I have to provide path manually.

When I remove **.spec** from file it magically starts working and gives me hints to automatically import classes.

When I add **.spec** it stops working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can just rename **spec.ts** to **test.ts** and then it somehow works